# How can I access ngOffline directive in a component instead of html

Tags: npm, offline, angular-directive, angular11

I'm using this npm library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-offline to alert end user when offline.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ngOffline>You're offline. Check your connection!</div>
```

stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngoffline-npm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Works great - **BUT** I want to open a modal with this **ngOffline** directive, so I'm trying to access the directive from my angular 11 component but not sure how to approach this, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Is there away for me to open a ngx-bootstrap modal from the html with this directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `ng-offline` module isn't exporting things as you might expect (i.e. you can't inject a standalone `NgOfflineDirective` for you to use without having it in your html file), you could add a block like this (where you've used `#trigger` to identify your `ngOnline` element):

```js
import { AfterContentChecked, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ ... })
export class YourClass implements AfterContentChecked, OnDestroy {
  offline$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
  subscription: Subscription;

  @ViewChild('trigger') trigger: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.subscription = this.offline$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter((offline: boolean) => offline),
    ).subscribe(() => this.showModal());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (
      this.trigger &&
      this.trigger.nativeElement
    ) {
      this.offline$.next(this.trigger.nativeElement.style.display === "none");
    }
  }

  showModal() {
    console.log('Show your modal here.');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, as it it an angular application - I tried your answer but used hostlistener instead but unfortunately couldn't get it to work - @HostListener("window:ngOffline", ["$event"])
  openOfflineModal() {
    this.offlineModal.show();
  }

Comment: Okay, but I literally added that line into your typescript and it worked as expected. :/

Comment: it does open an alert but does not use the library I am using from npm also your solution picks up the local/browser network whereas the ngOffline package on npm detects if you have no wifi/internet - I need to open a modal using the package from npm mentioned above in a component instead of the html - do you have any other suggestions? - I'd be delighted to hear them, thanks for the help so far ;)

Comment: I actually pulled that line out of the source for `ngOffline`. It looks like there's an additional poll to a URL to check response headers.

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz with your code and trying to hide/show the modals based on the wifi connection - initially with your code - the modal was displaying when connected to the internet but I want to show the modal when the user gets disconnected - it'd be great if you could fork my stackblitz and share the link - I'm missing something small but can't see it - really appreciate the help you've given me so far

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry that I was confusing. The `display === "none"` should be paired with an `ngOnline` element. If you are targeting an `ngOffline` directive, you'd use `display === "inherit"`.

Comment: thank you so much - works perfect - Now I need to hide the modal when back online, thanks again